# Foreign keys in ManyToMany Java + Hibernate + MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, mapping, many-to-many

When I am trying to delete Role from the roles table with the help of Hibernate using its id it occurs an exception:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ewp`.`permissions`, CONSTRAINT `FK_sq51ihfrapwdr98uufenhcocg` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`))
```

`Class User
...
    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Role.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "permissions",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;
...`

`Class Role
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> users;
...`

When I add to Role

`@JoinTable(name = "permissions",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    private List<User> users;`

Roles deleted without exceptions.
But I think that it can work without mapping in Role.

Comment: Have you tried adding mappedBy on the owned side? @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="roles")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to determine which side of the Many-To-Many owns the relationship or make sure that you alter both sides prior to removing the associated `Role` objects.

As mentioned in the comments, you can imply ownership by adding a `mappedBy` attribute to either side of the relationship. By adding `mappedBy="roles"` to the `Role` entity, this will tell the persistence provider that the relationship is managed by the `User` object's `roles` property and thus to manipulate the relationship using its join-table mapping.